# C++ using const in object constructor and member functions

Tags: c++

This is kind of two questions in one :-D.

I am getting a couple a compilation errors when trying to use const.

What I am trying to achieve.

In my class constructor I pass a pointer to an object. I do not want the address and value of the object to change so I use const. Here is what my code looks like

Class Constructor

```
A::A( const B* const example ): m_example(example) {

      m_mth1_ex = m_example->method1();
      m_mth2_ex = m_example->method2();

 }
```

In Class Header File

```
C* const m_mth1_ex;
D* const m_mth2_ex ;
```

Error that I am receiving:

```
error: uninitialized member 'A::m_mth1_ex' with 'const' type 'C* const'
error: uninitialized member 'A::m_mth2_ex' with 'const' type 'D* const'
error: assignment of read-only data-member 'A::m_mth1_ex'
error: assignment of read-only data-member 'A::m_mth1_ex'
```

I thought since I am initializing these values in constructor this was alright, but I guess I declare them in the header file and const do not like that...

Secondly, the methods from class B do not return const objects does this matter?

Lastly, Since the methods come from class B which has a const value and address will can these methods change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not initializing those values, you are assigning to them and compiler complaints because you cannot assign values to constant (read-only) variables. You have to use constructor's initialization list in order to initialize class members. For example:

```
A::A (const B *const example)
    : m_example (example)
    , m_mth1_ex (m_example->method1 ())
    , m_mth2_ex (m_example->method2 ())
{
}
```

Also, because order of declaration of the members matters, you have to be careful and watch out for the order of initialization. Basically, if you declare  `m_example` after `m_mth1_ex` inside a class, this code will be undefined behavior, because `m_mth1_ex` will get initialized first, even though it appears in the initialization list second.

In this particular example, it is safer to write this:

```
A::A (const B *const example)
    : m_example (example)
    , m_mth1_ex (example->method1 ())
    , m_mth2_ex (example->method2 ())
{
}
```

Another important thing to remember about initialization list and constructors in general - if exception is thrown in constructor, destructor of that object is not called. So, if your `method1 ()` and `method2 ()` calls allocate memory, then this code is bad because once `example->method2 ()` throws, you loose a pointer allocated by `example->method1 ()` and have a memory leak. Unless `m_mth1_ex` and `m_mth2_ex` are some kind of smart pointers (i.e. `std::unique_ptr`).

Comment: I believe I will have this very problem in the constructor. I will need to overload new operator or even better use smart pointers as you say :-D

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing **initialization** and **assignment**. The former is OK, the latter is not.

Use initialization properly:

```
A::A(const B* const example)
: m_example(example),
  m_mth1_ex(m_example->method1()),
  m_mth2_ex(m_example->method2())
{
}
```

(You might even prefer to use `example->method1()` to decouple yourself from any particular declaration order of the member variables.)

Answer (score 0):

`const` members **must** be initialized in an initializer list, so this means you must do this:

```
A::A( const B* const example )
:  m_example(example),
   m_mth1_ex = m_example->method1(),
   m_mth2_ex = m_example->method2()
{
}
```

However, now you've opened a huge can of worms with respect to order-of-initialization and maintainability.  Members are initialized in the order of declaration, regardless of in what order you initialize them according to the code you've written.  So, if `m_meth1_ex` is declared before `m_example`, `m_meth1_ex` will be initialized first.

The above will work -- but you probably have a design flaw in your code.  I would look in to coming up with a better design.